# Multiple columns from same table then order each column desc and sum columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I've been trying solve this but I can't find solution. I tried pivot but it did not work
I have a table like this

| ID Port | Date | Value | Empresa | Proveedor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 10:00 | 5 | A | ZZ |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 11:00 | 5 | A | ZZ |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 12:00 | 15 | A | ZZ |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 13:00 | 9 | A | ZZ |
| 1 | 01/01/2022 14:00 | 25 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 10:05 | 7 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 11:05 | 11 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 12:05 | 30 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 13:05 | 18 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 14:05 | 5 | A | ZZ |
| 2 | 01/01/2022 15:05 | 14 | A | ZZ |
| 3 | 01/01/2022 10:00 | 27 | A | ZZ |
| 3 | 01/01/2022 11:00 | 24 | A | ZZ |
| 3 | 01/01/2022 12:00 | 6 | A | ZZ |
| 3 | 01/01/2022 13:00 | 17 | A | ZZ |
| 3 | 01/01/2022 14:00 | 13 | A | ZZ |
| 4 | 01/01/2022 10:00 | 12 | B | YY |
| 4 | 01/01/2022 11:00 | 29 | B | YY |
| 4 | 01/01/2022 12:00 | 16 | B | YY |
| 4 | 01/01/2022 13:00 | 13 | B | YY |
| 4 | 01/01/2022 14:00 | 12 | B | YY |
| 5 | 01/01/2022 10:00 | 19 | B | YY |
| 5 | 01/01/2022 11:00 | 25 | B | YY |
| 5 | 01/01/2022 12:00 | 23 | B | YY |
| 5 | 01/01/2022 13:00 | 5 | B | YY |
| 5 | 01/01/2022 14:00 | 20 | B | YY |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 10:00 | 5 | C | XX |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 11:00 | 14 | C | XX |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 12:00 | 12 | C | XX |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 13:00 | 13 | C | XX |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 14:00 | 28 | C | XX |
| 6 | 01/01/2022 15:00 | 15 | C | XX |

And I want something like this

Total by Empresa A with Proveedor ZZ
Sort desc each port and sum in total

| Port1 | Port2 | Port3 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 30 | 27 | 82 |
| 15 | 18 | 24 | 57 |
| 9 | 14 | 17 | 40 |
| 5 | 11 | 13 | 29 |
| 5 | 7 | 6 | 18 |
| NULL | 5 | NULL | 5 |

Total by Empresa B with Proveedor YY
Sort desc each port and sum in total

| Port4 | Port5 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 25 | 54 |
| 16 | 23 | 39 |
| 13 | 20 | 33 |
| 12 | 19 | 31 |
| 12 | 5 | 17 |

Total by Empresa C with Proveedor XX

| Port 6 |
| --- |
| 28 |
| 15 |
| 14 |
| 13 |
| 12 |
| 5 |

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `PIVOT` clause

```sql
SELECT MAX("Port1") AS "Port1",
       MAX("Port2") AS "Port2",
       MAX("Port3") AS "Port3",
       MAX("Port4") AS "Port4",
       MAX("Port5") AS "Port5",
       MAX("Port6") AS "Port6",
       MAX(NVL("Port1", 0)) + MAX(NVL("Port2", 0)) + MAX(NVL("Port3", 0)) +
       MAX(NVL("Port4", 0)) + MAX(NVL("Port5", 0)) + MAX(NVL("Port6", 0)) AS "Total"
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Proveedor, Empresa, ID_Port ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
          FROM t
         WHERE Proveedor = '&p_Proveedor') -- substitute ZZ, YY or XX when prompted 
  PIVOT(
         MAX(value) FOR ID_Port IN( 1 AS "Port1", 2 AS "Port2", 3 AS "Port3", 
                                    4 AS "Port4", 5 AS "Port5", 6 AS "Port6")
        )
 GROUP BY rn
 ORDER BY rn
```

or *Conditional Aggregation* such as

```sql
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=1 THEN value END) AS "Port1",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=2 THEN value END) AS "Port2",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=3 THEN value END) AS "Port3",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=4 THEN value END) AS "Port4",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=5 THEN value END) AS "Port5",
       MAX(CASE WHEN ID_Port=6 THEN value END) AS "Port6",
       SUM(NVL(value,0)) AS "Total"
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Proveedor, Empresa, ID_Port ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
          FROM t
         WHERE Proveedor = '&p_Proveedor') -- substitute ZZ, YY or XX when prompted 

 GROUP BY rn
 ORDER BY rn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99fd564d8d752302751672cf48efbc24)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much Barbaros, seconds option works, appreciate your help.

Comment: you're welcome @atorresf , have a nice study. Btw, you can check out [dynamic-pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-pivot%2boracle?tab=Frequent) tag as exploring the dynamic alternatives...